# Scope in lambda

Tags: elisp, variables, lexical-scoping, dynamic-scoping

In my `.emacs` conf file, I've got this function that adds a hook to set the `compile-command` based on the mode. It looks something like,

```
(defun set-compile-cmd (mode-hook cmd)
  (add-hook mode-hook (lambda () 
    (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command) cmd))))
```

But I get an error that says value of symbol `cmd` is void. Shouldn't `cmd` exist in the scope of the lambda as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it shouldn't, if you use dynamic binding. Here are two choices (alternatives) that can help:

1. Use lexical binding.  Set variable `lexical-binding` for the file.
2. Use dynamic binding (what you are doing now, no doubt), but also substitute the **value** of the variable `cmd` for the **variable** `cmd` in the `lambda` body. You can do this only if the function body of the `lambda` does not actually need `cmd` to be a variable when it is invoked and can get by with just its value (its value at the time the function is added to the hook).

For **#1**, see node
[`Using Lexical Binding`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html)
in the Elisp manual. Essentially, you'll have to add `-*- lexical-binding: t; -*-` 
to the end of the first line of the file.

For **#2**, you do this:

```
(add-hook mode-hook `(lambda () (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command) ',cmd))))
```

For information about this, see node [`Backquote`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) in the Elisp manual.

In the case of #2, what is added to the hook is a textual `lambda` expression. It is interpreted (and so invoked) as a function only **when the hook is run**.

In the case of #1, the function (a closure, actually) corresponding to the `lambda` expression is interpreted as (understood to be) a function **when it is added to the hook**, and it can thus even be byte-compiled.

The closure contains a variable binding of `cmd` to the value it had when the function was added to the hook), as part of the function code (compiled or not).

This means that when that function is invoked any code that it runs has **access to `cmd` as a variable** at that time (not just a value).  If you don't really need a variable `cmd` at that time and a value will do, and if you don't care about byte-compiling the `lambda` code, then #1 is typically adequate.